# An easy way to output an array in a single line

Tags: arrays, powershell, string-formatting

I have an array in a line of `$a=@(1,2,3,4,56)`. When I do `Write-Debug $a` I get an exception in a line of "Array is not a String". If I do `$a | out-string | write-debug` I get a list of values in a column. I can write a function that'll write an array in a row (or a string without newlines), but I'd like to know if I'm inventing a bicycle that exists in Powershell, so I can use an existing solution.

Is there a built in function or a not too fancy one-liner to display an array in a format similar to `(1,2,3,4,56)`?

Comment: You don't need the `@( )`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, using `-join`:

```
$a -join ','
```

Comment: awesome! way cleaner then doing a foreach imo

Comment: In case you want to output as multiple lines, ``$a -join "`n"`` does the job.